# Como incluir data corrente em um JavaDoc gerado?

Tags: java, javadoc

Eu estou usando [jAutodoc](http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/) para gerar JavaDocs automaticamente, aqui um exemplo:

```
/**
## type: class|interface|enum
 * The ${e.getType().fu()} ${e}.
 * 
 * 
 * @author Edson 
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @date    11/09/2015
 * 
 */
```

Minha dúvida é, como incluir a data corrente no JavaDoc gerado ?

Eu tentei:

```
 * @date    new java.util.Date();
```

Porém, isso não teve efeito algum.

Desde já agradeço !

Comment: Acredito que [esta pergunta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318805/in-eclipse-how-to-automatically-print-current-date-time-in-the-comments) lhe ajude.

Comment: Obrigado Felipe, é realmente isso, se você quiser adicionar uma resposta, eu adiciono ela como correta !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode configurar nas preferências do Eclipse este modelo/template.

1. Vá até Windows/Preferences.
2. Na opção Editor -> Templates, adicione um novo e na seção "Modelo/Pattern" você informa `${date}${time}`.

[Fonte da pesquisa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318805/in-eclipse-how-to-automatically-print-current-date-time-in-the-comments)